# Spring's JavaMailSenderImpl throws an exception but still sends the email

Tags: java, spring, email, jakarta-mail

Using Spring 3.0, I wrote an interface to hide from the application which template engine I was using for sending mail. The interface is

```
public interface MailSender {
    public void send(String[] to, String from, String subject, String template,
        Map<Object, Object> model, boolean isHtml,
        Map<String, Resource> attachments,
        Map<String, Resource> inline) throws MailException;
}
```

Then the Velocity implementation is

```
public class MailSenderVelocity implements MailSender {
    private JavaMailSender sender;
    private VelocityEngine engine;

    @Override
    public void send(final String[] to, final String from,
        final String subject, final String template,
        final Map<Object, Object> model, final boolean isHtml,
        final Map<String, Resource> attachments,
        final Map<String, Resource> inline)
            throws com.engrid.mail.MailException {
        try {
            // prepare the message to send
            MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
                @Override
                public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
                    // determine if the message needs to be multipart or not
                    boolean multipart = (attachments != null && !attachments.isEmpty()) || (inline != null && !inline.isEmpty());

                    // create the message
                    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, multipart);

                    // populate header fields
                    helper.setTo(to);
                    helper.setFrom(from);
                    helper.setSubject(subject);

                    // fetch template and merge model
                    String text = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(engine, template, model);
                    helper.setText(text, isHtml);

                    // add inline attachments
                    if (inline != null) {
                        for (Entry<String, Resource> entry : inline.entrySet()) {
                            helper.addInline(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                        }
                    }

                    // add other attachments
                    if (attachments != null) {
                        for (Entry<String, Resource> entry : attachments.entrySet()) {
                            helper.addAttachment(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            // send the email
            this.sender.send(preparator);
        } catch(MailException e) {
            // error preparing or sending the message
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new com.engrid.mail.MailException(e);
        }
    }    

    public void setSender(JavaMailSender sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    public void setEngine(VelocityEngine engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }
}
```

Being a good programmer, I wrote test cases for different scenarios to ensure everything works correctly. One of my cases is when an attachment is specified but the file itself does not exist, specifically

```
@Test(expected=MailException.class)
public void testSend_MissingAttachment() throws IOException, MailException {
    // create new object
    MailSenderVelocity testSender = new MailSenderVelocity();
    testSender.setEngine(engine);
    testSender.setSender(sender);

    // assign properties
    String subject = "testSend_MissingAttachment";
    String template = "simple.vm";
    Map<Object, Object> model = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
    model.put("user", "User");
    boolean isHtml = true;
    Map<String, Resource> attachments = new HashMap<String, Resource>();
    String file = "notext.txt";
    attachments.put(file, templateDirectory.createRelative(file));
    Map<String, Resource> inline = null;

    // send a message -- will fail because it won't find the file to attach
    testSender.send(this.to, this.from, subject, template, model, isHtml, attachments, inline);
}
```

Now, the test results in the expected exception being thrown

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
nested exception is:
  java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/company/mail/template/notext.txt] cannot be opened because it does not exist; message exception details (1) are:
 Failed message 1:
 javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
   nested exception is:
  java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/company/mail/template/notext.txt] cannot be opened because it does not exist
  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:625)
  at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:416)
  at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:340)
  at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:355)
  at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:344)
  at com.company.mail.MailSenderVelocity.send(MailSenderVelocity.java:103)
  at com.company.mail.MailSenderVelocity.send(MailSenderVelocity.java:53)
  at com.company.mail.MailSenderVelocityTest.testSend_MissingAttachment(MailSenderVelocityTest.java:136)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:22)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
  at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:46)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:45)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/company/mail/template/notext.txt] cannot be opened because it does not exist
  at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)
  at org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper$1.getInputStream(MimeMessageHelper.java:1086)
  at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:302)
  at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1350)
  at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:845)
  at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.writeTo(MimeMultipart.java:361)
  at com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed.writeTo(multipart_mixed.java:85)
  at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:881)
  at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:314)
  at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1350)
  at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1683)
  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:585)
  ... 38 more
 2010-11-11 13:50:30,261
```

However, an email message still gets sent out to the listed recipient from the listed sender. All other things (subject, body, etc) are blank. How do I stop the email being sent when an exception is generated while building the email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting. It seems that Sun's internal JavaMail implementation is tolerating exceptions being thrown by the attachment handlers, and is carrying on regardless.

The easiest solution I can think of is to do a bit of up-front validation of your attachment resources, e.g.

```
for (Entry<String, Resource> entry : inline.entrySet()) {
   entry.getValue().getInputStream(); // validate the resource - fails if not existing
   helper.addInline(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

This will eagerly check that the `Resource` is available. You can also use `Resource.exists()` for this sort of thing if you choose.

Comment: That makes sense. I've changed the loops in the preparator to have a conditional -- if (!entry.getValue().exists()) throw new MailException("attachment[" + entry.getKey() + "] does not exist"); -- before adding the file and it works. Thanks for the suggestion!